# Conditional Column Creation DF Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am having trouble creating a column based on a Boolean conditional that maps a sum of 3 columns if True and average of the same three columns if False.  I saw a few stack questions that could map simple string identifiers but can't seem to get my equations to work.  I solved my issue with a very clunky function method which I will show as well.  But would like to see if anyone has a solution for a more efficient and potentially dynamic way of creating the fields.

Data:

```
import os
import sys
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
import random

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['howdy_man_dude', 'howdy_dude', 'howdy_man_dude', 'howdy_dude',
                        'howdy_dude', 'howdy_dude', 'howdy_man_dude', 'howdy_dude'],
                 '01-18' : np.random.randn(8).round(2),
                 '02-18' : np.random.randn(8).round(2), 
                 '03-18' : np.random.randn(8).round(2),
                 '04-18' : np.random.randn(8).round(2),
                 '05-18' : np.random.randn(8).round(2),
                 '06-18' : np.random.randn(8).round(2)})
pattern = '_man_'

df['man'] = df['A'].str.contains(pattern)



print(df)
   01-18  02-18  03-18  04-18  05-18  06-18               A    man
0  -1.47  -1.21  -0.06   0.12  -1.54   0.10  howdy_man_dude   True
1   1.27   0.11  -0.42  -0.20  -1.76   0.47      howdy_dude  False
2  -0.24   1.02   1.33  -0.59  -1.67   0.21  howdy_man_dude   True
3  -0.36   0.54   1.79   0.14   1.40   1.11      howdy_dude  False
4   0.31   0.40   0.21  -0.00   0.81  -1.29      howdy_dude  False
5   1.09  -0.47   2.43   0.30  -1.28   0.54      howdy_dude  False
6  -0.24  -0.19   0.48   1.94  -0.61  -0.51  howdy_man_dude   True
7   1.71  -0.80   0.94   2.47  -0.76  -0.26      howdy_dude  False
```

These either throw errors, or create a list of lists that I can't easily add as a column:

```
a =  df['man'].map(lambda x: (df['01-18']+df['02-18']+df['03-18']) if x == True else (df['01-18']+df['02-18']+df['03-18'])/3 )
a =  df['man'].map((df['01-18']+df['02-18']+df['03-18']) if df['man']==True else (df['01-18']+df['02-18']+df['03-18'])/3 )
a =  df.map((df['01-18']+df['02-18']+df['03-18']) if df['man']==True else (df['01-18']+df['02-18']+df['03-18'])/3 )
```

My function will get me what I need (quarterly summation or averages based on df['man'] but I have to redefine column indexes to get the subsequent quarter:

```
def boolAgg(vals):
    d=[]
    for ind,val in enumerate(vals):
        if val == True:
            d.append(df.iloc[ind,0]+df.iloc[ind,1]+df.iloc[ind,2])
        else:
            d.append((df.iloc[ind,0]+df.iloc[ind,1]+df.iloc[ind,2])/3)
    return d 



df['Q_1'] = boolAgg(df['man'])
```

Gets me Q1, now I redefine and run for Q2:

```
def boolAgg(vals):
    d=[]
    for ind,val in enumerate(vals):
        if val == True:
            d.append(df.iloc[ind,3]+df.iloc[ind,4]+df.iloc[ind,5])
        else:
            d.append((df.iloc[ind,3]+df.iloc[ind,4]+df.iloc[ind,5])/3)
    return d  

df['Q_2'] = boolAgg(df['man'])
```

Is there a simpler way to do this?  A perfect solution would be able to use a dictionary of possible equations (std.dev, sum, average etc, so more than just a Boolean T/F could be mapped) and be able to use a loop to automatically take the next three columns as the set (i.e. replicating 3 months in a quarter - to develop a quarterly time series) and creating the Q2, Q3, …. Qn  columns.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using `pd.Series.map` or manual row iteration for simple Boolean conditions. Instead, you can use `numpy.where`.

For example, replace the following...

```
a =  df['man'].map(lambda x: (df['01-18']+df['02-18']+df['03-18']) if x == True \
                             else (df['01-18']+df['02-18']+df['03-18'])/3 )
```

...with vectorised logic:

```
sums_1_2_3 = df[['01-18', '02-18', '03-18']].sum(axis=1)
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['man'], sums_1_2_3, sums_1_2_3 / 3)
```

Alternatively:

```
sum_1_2_3 = df[['01-18', '02-18', '03-18']].sum(axis=1)
mean_1_2_3 = df[['01-18', '02-18', '03-18']].mean(axis=1)

df['new_col'] = np.where(df['man'], sum_1_2_3, mean_1_2_3)
```

As well as making your code cleaner, this will ensure you are utilizing the NumPy arrays underlying your Pandas dataframe. You will see significant performance benefits versus `pd.Series.map` + `lambda`, which is just a thinly veiled loop.

Comment: Not sure it'd make a great difference, but an alternative alternative is: `aggs = df[['01-18', '02-18', '03-18']].T.agg(['sum', 'mean'])` - then `np.where(df['man'], aggs.loc['sum'], aggs.loc['mean'])`...

Comment: @JonClements, Yeh that's a very good option :). Would like to get some buy-in from OP first that this is the kind of thing he wants.

Comment: Suppose... `df[[...]].T.agg(...).T` is an option because for some reason those `.loc`s bug me...

Comment: Beautimous! now I'll have to devise a looping plan to select the next 3 months to create the subsequent calculation